# Создание класса MyArray без использование массивов

Tags: javascript

Представим, что массивов в Javascript нет; нужно написать класс MyArray (используя знания из предыдущих глав книги, прототипы пока не пройдены). Вот мой вариант кода:

```
function MyArray() {
    this.array = "";
    this.length = 0;
    var separator = "#$#s";
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this.array += arguments[i] + separator;
        this.length++;
    }
}
var a = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, "test");
```

Вопрос: не понимаю, как сделать так, чтобы `a[a.length - 1]` выдавал нужный результат?

Comment: зачем вам separator?

Comment: я использую строку для хранения данных, чтобы отделять элементы массива, я использую separator

Comment: не делайте так лучше... а вдруг вам содержимое элемента массива изменится, а вдруг массив изменится... Вы обрекаете себя на проблемы)

Comment: Как по другому хранить данные, не используя при этом массив (задача такая) ?

Comment: Никак) Вы всегда явно или не явно будете работать с массивом)

Comment: А теперь на вход передадим несколько объектов...

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyArray() {
    this.array = "";
    this.length = 0;
    var separator = "#$#s";
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        this.array += arguments[i] + separator;
        this.length++;
        this[i] = arguments[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Очень надеюсь, что ответите на следующий вопрос: что происходит в объекте при записи 'this[i] = arguments[i];'? Если описывать по шагам: создается массив, или указатель внутренний или что то еще?

Comment: Объект в данном случае используется, как ассоциативный массив, то есть "структура, позволяющая связывать произвольные значения с произвольными данными" (Флэнаган).

Comment: Ясно, спасибо!

Comment: Ассоциативный массив - это не массив, который Array, у экземпляра MyArray нет методов Array (join, concat, slice и пр.). Наверное, интересным заданием было бы их реализовать в MyArray :)

Comment: Задача как раз в этом и состоит, чтобы реализовать данные функции, но без использования массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Не идеальный вариант, но:

```
function MyArray() {
  for ( var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++ ) this[i] = arguments[i];
  this.length = i;

  this.toString = function (){
      var i, res = '';
      for ( i = 0; i < this.length; i++ ) res += this[i] + ', ';
      return '['+res + ']';
  }
}

arr = new MyArray( 1,2,3,4,5,6 );
console.log( arr.toString() );
```

Comment: Вроде бы так, но получается, что используется ассоциативный массив, возможно так и нужно, но автор указал "без использования массивов". С другой стороны, 'a[a.length - 1]' без массива не сможет работать, как я понимаю.

Comment: В JS - всё ассоциативный массив) Поэтому такая постановка вопроса не корректна)<br>
Вы всегда явно или не явно будете работать с массивом)

Comment: В смысле любой объект может им быть? Теперь стал больше понимать в Javascript, спасибо! )

Comment: Объект - это ассоциативный массив)